# How to sustain access to Gmail API without storing sensitive user data?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, oauth, oauth-2.0, gmail-imap

What is the preferred method of accessing the Gmail API across sessions without user input? E.g. user logs in once, some fairly-non-sensitive ID is stored on my server, and I use that ID along with my app's secret/key to access user's mailbox...

I noticed that OAuth 1.0 is now deprecated by google (I'm assuming that OAuth 1.0 enables the aforementioned login mechanism), so what should we use? Does OAuth 2.0 + IMAP work with Gmail?

I'm using a Rails 3.2.6 backend.

Comment: You need IMAP access to the account? If yes, the id would not really be "non-sensitive", but better than storing the password :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without storing the user's password, the only way for full GMail access is using [IMAP/SMTP with OAuth 1](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/gmail/oauth_overview). With OAuth 2 you currently can only access the [Atom Inbox Feed](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/gmail/gmail_inbox_feed).

Though OAuth 1 was already marked deprecated by Google, it should be [supported until April 2015](https://developers.google.com/accounts/terms).

**UPDATE:**

OAuth 2 authorization support for GMail IMAP/SMTP just [recently arrived](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/gmail/oauth_overview), so this is now the recommended way to go.

Comment: Great, thanks for your response, Jan!  I don't think the atom feed would work for me, as I need to be able to search for specific phrases in users' inboxes, but IMAP + OAuth 1.0 should do. 2015 is far enough for now ;)

Comment: @JaredGoodner OAuth 2 supports is now available.

Answer (score 0):

I don't find any information in the [oAuth API docs](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/gmail/oauth_overview) about oAuth 1.0 being deprecated.

However oAuth 2.0 seems to be there as well for Gmail: [oAuth 2.0 Playground](https://code.google.com/oauthplayground/).

Comment: I can't seem to find the doc that reported deprecation of OAuth 1.0, but I saw it somewhere...Maybe someone here has seen it too? As @Jan Gerlinger reported above, it appears that OAuth 2.0 only works with the Gmail Atom feed, which (correct me if I'm wrong) wouldn't allow me to query through old emails